# How do I log all sql calls to a file in cakephp2?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I found examples of how to extend the db class in cake 1 to log files to sql, but these dont seem compatible with cake 2.

I have a controller edit/update function that does an insert on the post, this doesn't get logged using 
        element('sql_dump'); ?>

because the calls happen on the post, not on the rendering of the page.

I also tried debug_kit but it seems to log the same stuff as sql_dump, and doesn't show this info.

Also it would be nice to log all request parameters for each controller call, I think I can get this out of debug_kit, but it would be easier to use in a log file.

thanks
Joel

Answer (score 0):

Go to sql_dump.ctp file in element and write log to file using cake method as bellow

```
$this->log('your_sql_log');
```

This will be written in file inside

```
tmp/logs/error.log
```

file. hope this will work for u